# text View not displaying in scroll View, inside Android emulator

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I created a simple app that displays Name of user and her bio inside a scroll View. At initial stage, when I just added a TextView, an ImageView and a TextView inside Scroll View.. but when I ran the app.. it just showed the uppermost TextView with the star ImageView I just added, and not the contents of ScrollView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rootLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/padding"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/padding">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameTextView"
        style="@style/nameStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/shivam_jha" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/starImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/layout_margin"
        android:contentDescription="@string/star"
        tools:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/bioScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/layout_margin">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bioTextView"
            style="@style/nameStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.1"
            tools:text="@string/test" />
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the string resource file:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">About Me App</string>
    <string name="shivam_jha">Shivam Jha</string>
    <string name="star">star</string>
    <string name="test">Hey, this is demo string</string>


</resources>
```

And this the dimensions resource file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="text_size">20sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="small_padding">8dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="layout_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="padding">6dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

This is the styles resource file:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="nameStyle">
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">@dimen/layout_margin</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/roboto</item>
        <item name="android:paddingTop">@dimen/small_padding</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

[image: Emulator Screen After App Run]

Comment: Can you rephrase the question or add a screenshot of your result

Comment: I've added the screenshot after app run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after searching through the code for a while, I came to know that for showing the text inside Scroll View, I was using `tool` namespace instead of `app`.
`tool` namespace is only used for dummy data: the data which is automatically deleted at compile time.

So, I removed the following line:

```
tool:text="@string/bio" />
```

With:

```
android:text="@string/bio" />
```

And now, everything works right!
Thanks Nikhil and potter soln for help :)

[image: Screenshot of final result]

Answer (score 0):

You can try using LinearLayout in the Scroll view and TextView in the LinearLayout.
Like this:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bioTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.1"
            style="@style/nameStyle"
            tools:text="123" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Try this solution.

Comment: It didn't help.. while it is a common practice to add things inside a Linear Layout inside Scroll View, I don't  find it necessary to add Linear Layout for a simple thing.. just one thing, TextView.. Still same output after app run

Answer (score 0):

You are still using LinearLayout. I would suggest you move to Constraint Layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView15"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:text="Your name"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView15">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView18"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="t vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: It didn't help.. still same output

Comment: Do you have any Wireframe of exact result you are trying to achive ?

Comment: Well, Nikhil, now everything's working fine, thanks for your help.. But "while it is a common practice to add things inside a Linear Layout inside Scroll View, I don't find it necessary to add Linear Layout for a simple thing.. just one thing, TextView"
I guess you should have a moment of thought on that

Comment: by the way, I liked your suggestion of Constraint Layout for better performance